# Prove that $\lim\inf_{x\to+\infty}\left|\frac{f'(x)}{(f(x))^{\frac{3}{2}}}\right|=0$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

For $f:(0,\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ differentiable such that $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} (x)^{\frac{1}{2}}f(x)=\infty$. Prove that $$\lim\inf_{x\to+\infty}\left|\frac{f'(x)}{(f(x))^{\frac{3}{2}}}\right|=0.$$

I observed that 
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}f(x)(f(x))^{\frac{1}{2}}=\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}xf(x)^{\frac{1}{2}}=\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}f'(x)xf(x)^{\frac{1}{2}}$$ and so the required limit simplifies and tends to $0$. But how can I handle the fact its an absolute value and an infimum?

Comment: @RobertZ It's $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} (x)^{\frac{1}{2}}f(x)=\infty$

Comment: No. It's $\lim\inf_{x\to+\infty}\left|\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)^{\frac{3}{2}}}\right|$